# Drawing the sun, moon or stars

Tags: halacha, art, moon

In what manner may one draw the sun, moon and stars for a children's book? Is there a difference if it's:

1. not complete
2. black and white outline or colored
3. realistic or fake looking
4. the purpose of the drawing

Comment: I have edited the question to avoid asking for personalized advice, which would get it closed. Feel free to revert, and btw welcome Mi Yodeya! For personalized advice, please go and ask your local orthodox Rabbi, even if answers are provided here.

Comment: Also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34193/what-can-a-jew-draw